# when parsing DateTime says Length cannot be less than zero

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

I am trying to parse a column in a datagrid which has time and date formatted as:

```
3:44 PM 22/02/2023 
10:58 PM 17/02/2023
```

The code below would successfully parse only the time which I have tested using `Debug.Writeline`, but once I try `DateTime.Parse`, I get an error:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Length cannot be less than zero. Arg_ParamName_Name'

Code:

```
string dateText = trade.Date.ToString();

int indexM = dateText.IndexOf('M');

if (indexM >= 0) // Check if 'M' exists in the string
{
    dateText = dateText.Substring(0, indexM + 1); // Include the 'M'
}

DateTime time = DateTime.Parse(dateText);
```

Comment: Are you sure the input is what you think it should be? With the given input, the code should work fine. Remark: I hope the `ToString()` is just for testing. Converting a date to a string to manipulate it is very bad style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we know actual format which is

```
h:m tt d/M/yyyy
```

why not use it with `ParseExact` and let .Net do the work for you?

```
using Ssytem.Globalization;

...

static DateTime MyParse(string text) => 
  DateTime.ParseExact(text, "h:m tt d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If several formats can be used (say with `AM/PM` or without), put them all:

```
static DateTime MyParse(string text) => DateTime.ParseExact(
  text, 
  new string[] {    // when parsing
    "h:m tt d/M/yyyy", //  try this first 
    "H:m d/M/yyyy"     //  if not fit, try this
  }, 
  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Having `DateTime` you can represent it in whatever format you like (via `ToString(formatString)`),  obtain `Date` or `TimeOfDay` etc.

Demo:

```
string[] tests = new string[] {
  "3:44 PM 22/02/2023",
  "10:58 PM 17/02/2023",
};

// Put "h:mm tt" format string to print time only
var result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
  .Select(test => $"{test,25} => {MyParse(test):dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss}"));

Console.Write(report);
```

Output:

```
       3:44 PM 22/02/2023 => 22.02.2023 15:44:00
      10:58 PM 17/02/2023 => 17.02.2023 22:58:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of troubleshooting, see what displays as your input when it catches the exception:

```
String dateText = trade.Date.ToString();

int indexM = dateText.IndexOf('M');
if (indexM >= 0) // Check if 'M' exists in the string
{
  dateText = dateText.Substring(0, indexM + 1); // Include the 'M'
}

DateTime time;
try  {
  time = DateTime.Parse(dateText);
  Console.WriteLine("time = " + time);
}
catch (Exception ex) {
  Console.WriteLine("Bad Input: " + dateText);
}
```

Comment: Why `try-catch` instead of `TryParse`?

Comment: @GuruStron "Just for the sake of troubleshooting" I wrote the code without the aid of an IDE, directly in the browser window. If I was using an IDE of some kind then I would have probably used something fancier. I just couldn't remember the exact syntax for the other approaches...

Answer (score 0):

Consider loading your DataGridView with a DataTable (or a list of T). If data being read in is not a date time use code provided by Dmitry Bychenko to create a proper date time. Formatting can be done in code or in the DataGridView designer.

DataGridView works without a DataSource but much better with a DataSource as everything is strong typed. Also, one need not access cell data, instead access cell data from the DataSource, in this case a BindingSource.

Example

[image]

Load the DataGridView, in this case with mocked data.

```cs
private readonly BindingSource _bindingSource = new BindingSource();
```

In an event

```
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "Id", DataType = typeof(int), 
    AutoIncrement = true, AutoIncrementSeed = 1, ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden});
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "DateColumn", DataType = typeof(DateTime)});

dt.Rows.Add(null, new DateTime(2023, 2, 22, 9, 44, 0));
dt.Rows.Add(null, new DateTime(2023, 2, 17, 10, 58, 0));
_bindingSource.DataSource = dt;
dataGridView1.DataSource = _bindingSource;
```

Setup date time format in the designer for `DefaultCellStyle` to `h:m tt d/M/yyyy`

Get current row date

```
private void CurrentButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_bindingSource.Current is not null)
    {
        var dateValue = ((DataRowView)_bindingSource.Current).Row.Field<DateTime>("DateColumn");
        MessageBox.Show($@"Date is {dateValue:h:mm:ss tt}");
    }
}
```

Iterate all rows

```
private void IterateRowsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dt = (DataTable)_bindingSource.DataSource;
    if (dt is null)
    {
        return;
    }
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(row.Field<DateTime>("DateColumn"));
    }
}
```